# HttpRequestValidationException and cross-site scripting XSS

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

By using HttpRequestValidationException, does it necessarily protect you against all cross-scripting threats?

Are there situations where a potentially dangerous script might manage to go undetected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in short it doesn't. Please decompile it using reflector and see what it does. An attack on an html attribute could be: " onfocus=alert(1) autofocus
There are no < or > in this yet it still works. Please use AntiXss and check the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet. So you need to pay attention especially whenever you are using unescaped attributes like Literal.

Comment: You are right about it not detecting attacks without < or >. Thank you for providing the AntiXss as a reference as well. I think it will prove to be a valuable resource.

Comment: I tried the following input --- " href="javascript:(alert('XSS!'))">CLICKKKKK --- and it was able to bypass HttpRequestValidationException. So you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in short it does.  It can't do everything related to XSS, like control what you are doing with JavaScript(`eval()...`etc).  As far as request being processed by your ASP.NET applications, it does a good job, there are always exceptions.