# Should asp.net developers take care of xss when request validation is enabled?

Tags: asp.net, xss, sql-injection

As a build-in feature, asp.net supports the request validation. So, when the request validation is enabled, should asp.net developers take care of xss? Is there still any way to complete xss attacking?

Similarly, should we take care of SQL Injection when using Linq2SQL or Entity Framework?

My team tends to don't filter the input strings manually because of the benefits of the asp.net and those two ORM tools...

Thanks~

Comment: I don't think we should bother doing that as Microsoft has already provided us those facilities.

Comment: YES, **[you should](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9733427/304683)**

Comment: thanks, @EdSF. The link you provided is helpful. And, how about the sql-injection?

Comment: At the end of the day, the posture you have to take as a web developer is **"trust no one"**. SQL injection is both an issue on the client side as well has how you write your queries - so if the "gateway" to them is user input, then sanitizing input should be 2nd nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the sql question first, linq2sql handles it for you. As long a you are not building queries by concatenating strings (paramdterized queries etc.), you are safe.

Regarding XSS, request validation is NOT enough. See my answer here: [Is PagesSection.ValidateRequest enough to prevent XSS in asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733427/is-pagessection-validaterequest-enough-to-prevent-xss-in-asp-net/9748588)