# Cross-site scripting and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, xss, cross-site

Does an ASP.NET application protect against cross-site scripting by default?  I have read that the machine.config file has an attribute that is set to on by default and this protects against cross-site scripting?  Is this true?

Comment: by default you cannot submit a script like tag to an ASP.NET form, on MVC every output get HTML encoded before being printed to the  client, so the answer is yes

Comment: Thanks :)  That's what I wanted to hear :)  So an ASP.NET application automatically protects against cross-site scripting by default?

Comment: xss is covered, csrf is not. You can try to create a simple form and test it yourself

Comment: Yes.  In fact I tested it on a web application of mine and when I entered characters like "<>", an exception was raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<system.web>
  <pages buffer="true" validateRequest="true" />
</system.web>
```

you can use antxss library as addition

Comment: Thanks :)  That's the line I was talking about.  That protects against cross-site scripting.  Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: That question has been asked many times before. The answer is "it depends on your app". See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733427/is-pagessection-validaterequest-enough-to-prevent-xss-in-asp-net/9748588